# Awk script only works if i edit the text file manually

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, expect, gawk

I'm using `awk` to organize the information in a text file (It contains CDP neighbors information of a switch taken from terminal) , the file looks like this:

```
Device ID Local Intrfce
BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6
N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
Gig 1/0/1 145
LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11
Arquitectura_Salones
Gig 1/0/9 147
CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4
Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3
ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10
ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7
Ingenieria_Posgrado
Gig 1/0/8 132
Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2
Electronica_Edif_3
Gig 1/0/5 173
Barragan_3750>exit
Connection closed by foreign host.
]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note
```

And i want it to looks like this:

```
Device ID Local Intrfce
BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6
N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL) Gig 1/0/1 145
LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11
Arquitectura_Salones Gig 1/0/9 147
CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4
Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3
ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10
ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7
Ingenieria_Posgrado Gig 1/0/8 132
Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2
Electronica_Edif_3 Gig 1/0/5 173
Barragan_3750>exit Connection closed by foreign host.
]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note
```

The awk script that i'm using is this:

```
awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (length($1) > 16) ? OFS : ORS}' CDPyPuerto.dat > TablaCDP.dat
```

It looks for those lines in which the first field has more than 16 characters and replace the break line with a space.

When i run the awk script the result looks like this:

```
Device ID Local Intrfce 
BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6 
N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)
  Gig 1/0/1 172 
LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11 
Arquitectura_Salones
  Gig 1/0/9 176 
CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4 
Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3 
ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10 
ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7 
Ingenieria_Posgrado
  Gig 1/0/8 159 
Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2 
Electronica_Edif_3
  Gig 1/0/5 141 
Barragan_3750>exit
Connection closed by foreign host.

]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note
```

I have noticed that **if i open the orginial text file (CDPyPuertos.dat) with gedit and edit something (e.g. add an space at the end of the file or change some character) the awk script works fine**, but all this is into an Expect script, so it should to be automatic, also i've tried to change the format of the file from ascci to UTF-8 but it didn't work, the same if i use different extensions (.txt .dat .dos)

Does anybody knows why is this happening?

Thanks by advance

Update:

If i type:  `cat -et CDPyPuerto.dat`

The result is this:

```
Device ID Local Intrfce$
BIOTERIO Gig 1/0/6$
N7K-LAN(JAF1651ANDL)^M$
Gig 1/0/1 165$
LAB_PESADO Gig 1/0/11$
Arquitectura_Salones^M$
Gig 1/0/9 173$
CIVIL_253 Gig 1/0/4$
Arquitectura Gig 1/0/3$
ING_CIVIL_DIR Gig 1/0/10$
ING_CIVIL Gig 1/0/7$
Ingenieria_Posgrado^M$
Gig 1/0/8 152$
Biblio_Barragan Gig 1/0/2$
Electronica_Edif_3^M$
Gig 1/0/5 133$
Barragan_3750>exit^M$
Connection closed by foreign host.^M$
^[]0;cesar@cesar-HP-Pavilion-15-Note$
```

After i open CDPyPuerto.dat with gedit and edit something, all the `^M$` turns into `$`.

How can i do it automatically?

Comment: Does your input file have Windows-style CR-LF line endings (check for example with `cat -et CDPyPuerto.dat`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd solve this is to remove the CR characters (represented as `^M` in the output from `cat -et`):

```
tr -d '\r' < CDPyPuerto.dat |
    awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (length($1) > 16) ? OFS : ORS}' > TablaCDP.dat
```